How to Derive Digital Filter Coefficients From Given Specifications
I am looking to further understand how to derive the coefficients of a digital filter from design specifications. For example, if I wanted a FIR Butterworth low pass filter with a pass band till 0.2 (Normalized Frequency) and a stop band at 0.3 with 80dB attenuation. In MATLAB it is easy to go to filterDesigner, type in those specifications, then export it as a matrix of coefficients. My gap in knowledge is how the tool derives the weights of those coefficients. Going from the system diagram to plotting out the response of the filter is fairly trivial (analysis), but being able to do the design aspect without the aid of a tool like filterDesigner is what I am struggling to understand.

The matlab documentation is actually good at explaining the algorithms it uses, often with citations to the papers where the algorithm originates.  I would start there, and then if you find something that isn't documented, try asking on the signal processing stack exchange.

There's multiple algotrithms for designing FIR filters. However, that belongs to the domain of digital signal processing, not electrical engineering.

Just in case you haven't red the elementaries of filter synthesis theory:
Mathematics in many older application areas than electronics needed continuous functions which approximate rectangular pulses. That's why such approximations were developed before there was any electronics. In filter design we use Butterworth, Tsebychev, Bessel and Cauer approximations of the idealized filters (=rectangular frequency response graphs). They all are in some different sense optimal and can be realized with circuits and they can as well be calculated in real time DSP.
The possibility to be realized with circuits or to be calculated in real time is not at all clear. A transfer function which looks good as a frequency response graph may actually present an unstable circuit or a circuit which can predict the future.
The unstability cannot be fixed by using DSP. Non-causality i.e. the ability to predict can be partially worked around in DSP by storing the whole signal and making the processing afterwards. But it's useless if the application needs real time filtering. As said, filters which use Butterworth, Tsebychev, Bessel and Cauer approximations of the rectangular response do not have such problems. Cauer (A.K.A elliptic) approximation is actually originally developed for filters. The others are much older.
How to generate DSP-versions of filters
One well known and somehow useful trick is to approximate in z-plane a good s-plane transfer function by making Bilinear Transformation. One substitutes s with a more or less complex expression of z. The mathematically exact (see NOTE1) substitute s=ln(z)/T, where T is the sample period, is not practical, but even its first order rational function approximation s=2(z-1)/((z+1)T) is useful. Read more from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_transform
Another possibility is to calculate the impulse response of the wanted filter and then

shorten the impulse response to a finite sequence by using some smooth fading window
build the canonical FIR filter which has the wanted impulse response.

The later method can be used even for the ideal rectangular frequency response if one accepts enough delay to make the windowing possible.
The third way is to use FFT. One can calculate FFT so fast that it's possible to apply the frequency response to the spectrum and then make the filtered signal by applying the inverse FFT.
This all written above is very rough. Get a book of DSP theory. Making approximations of approximations cause side effects and DSP itself has its own problems caused by the limited numerical precision. Proper engineering must take them into the account. Fortunately even hobbyists can today use the trial & error method by simulating the result in an ordinary computer.
NOTE1: As a formal algebraic manipulation that's a triviality. Variable s is solved from the Laplace transform of an unit delay. Proving that it's also meaningful is PhD level stuff.
